# I have an endless loop

Tags: delphi

```
newValue := oldValue;
repeat
    delta := (RandomRange(0, 200) / 100) - 1;
    newValue := newValue + delta;
 until (newValue > 24) and (newValue < 40);
 oldValue := newValue;


newValue2 := oldValue2;
repeat
    delta := (RandomRange(0, 200) / 100) - 1;
    newValue2 := newValue2 + delta;
 until (newValue2 > 24) and (newValue2 < 40) and (newValue2 < newValue); 
 oldValue2 := newValue2;
```

after a few iterations, this hits an endless loop in the second loop. It is meant to change a Float randomly by -1 to +1 and keep it in the range 24 to 40 while still being less than another Float which is being randomly changed in the same way.

Who can be first to make me say "d'oh!"?   (probably by `(newValue2 < newValue)`)

---

d'oh!

Well, now that it is pointed out, the answer is obvious.   `newValue := oldValue + delta;`, not ` newValue := newValue + delta;', so that the code reads (similar for both loops)

```
newValue := oldValue;
repeat
    delta := (RandomRange(0, 200) / 100) - 1;
    newValue := oldValue + delta;              <==== **NOT**  newValue
 until (newValue > 24) and (newValue < 40);
 oldValue := newValue;
```

Thanks, all, and lots of +1 all round

Comment: What do you mean that it hits an endless loop "after a few iterations"? If there's more than one iteration, then it's looping. There's no particular iteration in which a loop *becomes* endless. Either it's always endless, or it's not endless at all.

Comment: You just added the second section of code after I gave my answer. I'm not sure what the purpose of the second piece of code is. If the first section is not terminating, you'll never get to the second section.

Comment: Sorry about that Rob, you know how it is - always try to give a small example that is easy to understand, then mess it up. +1 to your comments.    There are two Floats which fluctuate randomly between 24 and 40. It works well for a while, then the second loop seems to loop forever, probably because the first variable hit either 24 or 40 and the second must be less than it.  I didn't think that important at firs, so only posted one loop, then I though tit might be. I'll think in future before posting.

Comment: Why are you not just generating a single random number? Assuming OldValue is within the range, you seem to be asking for NewValue to be within +-1 of that, then NewValue2 to be up to 1 less than NewValue. mgiuca's answer is correct - your code (and the "new" code) is not guaranteed to terminate and most people would regard that as a bug. I think review your requirements first, then try for new code.  If you do need it to terminate then the "generate one random number for each random number you need" is IMO the better way.

Comment: @Moz, the new code *is* guaranteed to terminate, at least for the first loop. I think it's safe to assume that `oldValue` is already within the legal range when the loop starts, and this code is only meant to select a new nearby value in the same range. If `oldValue` is *just* above 24, then any positive value of `delta` will terminate the loop. It *will* have a positive value eventually. The second loop, calculating `newValue2`, might not terminate because it has an added constraint related to `newValue`. If `newValue` is *just* above 24, then there's not much room for `newValue2`.

Comment: @Rob: I don't see how that's the case. If oldValue is in the range 25..39 then yes, the first loop must always terminate on the first iteration, but if OldValue is at one extremity of the range then it could take a while for the first loop to terminate (equivalent to the question "how many heads can I coin toss in a row"), and if newValue is at the lower end of the range the second loop cannot terminate. The lower end" here meaning the smallest posible float greater than 24.

Comment: @Rob, I think the "only generate as many random numbers as you need to" approach is still a better solution. I'd also love you to show how your guarantee works for the inputs oldvalue=24.1 and a random sequence composed entirely of zeros (which is a possible sequence, and thus must fall within the guarantee)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "keep it in the range 24 to 40"? Your condition "`until (newValue > 24) and (newValue < 40)`" implies that it will stop once it is in that range; it will go forever if it is outside that range.

The chances of it terminating depend upon `oldValue`. What values are you expecting `oldValue` to have?

In any case, such a loop is not guaranteed to terminate. You are changing the number randomly each time, so there is no guarantee it will move into the termination range at all. In particular, a large number of random numbers between -1 and 1 all added together will usually sum to approximately 0, so you can't expect the number to change significantly over time. It's probably the case that it happens never to enter that range.

Comment: +1 and the answer. I have updated the question to show the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

You set the value of `oldValue` twice, once after each loop. It looks like you really want to set the value of `oldValue2` after the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

While i don't know Delphi, I wonder what's going on with the `RandomRange` function.  The way its written, it looks as though `RandomRange` is getting you a number from 0 to 200, which you are then dividing by 100 to get a number from 0 to 2.  Then, you subtract 1, getting a number from -1 to 1.  If I read it correctly, then you the value should stay just about the same over time.

What do you get if you trace the values in the loop conditions?

Comment: +1 That describes very well what I am trying to do.  Yes, get a number from -1 to +1 and add to current value. It will average the same value, but can wander between 24 and 40, with the caveat that the send value cannot exceed the first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a delphi person so I could be way off (and I'll delete my answer if someone tells me I am) 
but won't the delta just as likely be away from zero negatively as it will be positively on each iteration. Or simplified just as likely to be -1 as it is +1.

If this is true won't the value of newValue over many iteration have almost no change?

**Update**

Or to clarify won't the sum of a lot of random numbers between -1 and 1 be very near zero.

In any case wouldn't be simpler to create a variable to hold the number of iterationsyou might want.

e.g.

```
repeatcount:= RandomRange(24,40)
num:0

repeat
  num := num +1
until (num = repeatcount)
```

or if you just want new value to be somewhere between 24 and 40

```
newValue := Random(24,40)
```

Comment: +1 You are correct, but since it is a Float, it will move, and I am measuring to several decimal digits of significance.